# Regex pattern for checking all type of Date format

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I want to check for date values present in which column of dataframe and convert the column to datetime because column type can be object initially, but dates can be in any format as below.
So I am looking for a regex pattern which will match all date type formats.

1. 04/10/2022
2. 10/04/2022
3. 2022/04/10
4. 2022/10/04
5. 2022-12-20 00:00:00
6. 04-10-2022

Can someone please suggest a regex pattern which will match all date formats?

I have tried below code:

```
    for columnIndex, colName in enumerate(df):

        df2 = pd.DataFrame()
        df2['test'] = df[colName]
        count = 0
        for i, j in df2.iteritems():
            for k in j:
                if re.match("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", str(k)):
                    count = count+1
        if(count>5):
            df[colName] = pd.to_datetime(df[colName])
        print(df.dtypes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea. With this code you will match all the formats, however you can't distinguish between days and month if the date is, say `05/05/2022`. But that is an issue that goes beyond the scope of the question.

The regexp I came up with looks for groups of one or more numbers `[0-9]+` separated by either the dash or the slash '[/-]', and I used the backslash to escape the special symbols.

```
dates="""04/10/2022
10/04/2022
2022/04/10
2022/10/04
2022-12-20 00:00:00
04-10-2022"""

import re
dre = re.compile(r"([0-9]+)[\/\-]([0-9]+)[\/\-]([0-9]+)")

for date in dates.split("\n"):
    m = dre.match(date)
    print( m.group(1) , m.group(2) , m.group(3) )
```

Comment: Hi Fra93, your solution worked on all date formats but also returning one column with values like 522-53-2510, How to exclude column with values like this

Comment: Nice catch! I believe that you either use the `to_datetime` function in pandas (best solution) or if you want a homemade script, you need to add some logic to the groups matched by the regexp, i.e. that the length is 2 or 4, and that the range is within some boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the following dataframe `df` with all date formats indicated by OP in the question

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['04/10/2022', '10/04/2022', '2022/04/10', '2022/10/04', '2022-12-20 00:00:00', '04-10-2022']})

[Out]:
                  date
0           04/10/2022
1           10/04/2022
2           2022/04/10
3           2022/10/04
4  2022-12-20 00:00:00
5           04-10-2022
```

Assuming the goal is to convert to datetime, one can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). This has the parameter `infer_datetime_format` that one can use as follows

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

[Out]:

        date
0 2022-04-10
1 2022-10-04
2 2022-04-10
3 2022-10-04
4 2022-12-20
5 2022-04-10
```

For this case, it does the work.

---

**Note:**

- If one wants to explore the source code to see how the function is implemented, [check the Github here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L706-L1110).

Comment: Just a curiosity: how does the `infer datetime format` work in case of an ambiguous date, like the first example? It could either be the 10th of April or the 4th of October.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) without providing any format ?

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)
        Col1       Col2       Col3       Col4
0 2022-04-10        NaT        NaT        NaT
1        NaT 2022-10-04        NaT        NaT
2        NaT        NaT 2022-04-10        NaT
3 2022-10-04        NaT        NaT        NaT
4        NaT        NaT        NaT 2022-12-20
5 2022-04-10        NaT        NaT        NaT
```

##### # Input used :

```
         Col1        Col2        Col3                 Col4
0  04/10/2022         NaN         NaN                  NaN
1         NaN  10/04/2022         NaN                  NaN
2         NaN         NaN  2022/04/10                  NaN
3  2022/10/04         NaN         NaN                  NaN
4         NaN         NaN         NaN  2022-12-20 00:00:00
5  04-10-2022         NaN         NaN                  NaN
```